# jQuery 1.10.1 setting non existing value on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Can someone explain this behavior:

```
<select id ="test">
       <option value="-1">---All---</option>
       <option value="1">first</option>
       <option value="2">second</option>
</select>

$('#test').val(200);
```

Using the jQuery 1.10.1 the value of the select is null,
but using jQuery 1.9.1 the value is the first option.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sH4H6/465/)

Comment: In general, when something doesn't work correctly in an older version and works correctly in a newer version, "they fixed it" is a reasonable guess. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using the jQuery 1.10.1 the value of the select is null, but using jQuery 1.9.1 the value is the first option.

It's the fix to [bug #13514](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13514), fixed in v1.10. Setting an invalid value should clear the select (which it does in v1.10+), not leave it at the default (first) option (v1.9).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to try,

```
$('#test').val(2);
```

`none` is `selected` (or default selected) if the drop-down value not exists.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/sH4H6/466/)

The issue comes in `Blackberry 4.7` having `attributes.value`

The change in `1.9 version` and `1.10 version` are

**jQuery 1.9.1 hook**

```
jQuery.extend({
    valHooks: {
        option: {
            get: function( elem ) {
                // attributes.value is undefined in Blackberry 4.7 but
                // uses .value. See #6932
                var val = elem.attributes.value;
                return !val || val.specified ? elem.value : elem.text;
            }
        },
```

And **jQuery 1.10 hook**

```
jQuery.extend({
    valHooks: {
        option: {
            get: function( elem ) {
                // Use proper attribute retrieval(#6932, #12072)
                var val = jQuery.find.attr( elem, "value" );
                return val != null ?
                    val :
                    elem.text;
            }
        }
```

Read [#6932 Blackberry 4.7: .val() on empty option fails](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6932)

Answer (score 0):

May be in jQuery 1.9.1 first is the default option if you provide any non-existing value while jQuery 1.10.1 don't select anything in such case.
You should pass value of `option` which you wan to select to [**val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/). 200 is a not present as value for any option.