# Dropdown doesn't contain empty value, still gets selected

Tags: jquery

I have a weird issue.

I have a dropdown with **no** empty value option i.e.

```
<option value="">Select</option>
```

My dropdown:

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

However, when I set the the dropdown value like so:

```
$('#dropdown').val("")
```

The dropdown shows an empty option eventhough there is no such option available in the list.
Why does this happen?
I've checked my code and the html and I don't find any empty option or any code that sets an empty option.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: See:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983511/jquery-1-10-1-setting-non-existing-value-on-select

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards that question. I searched but couldn't find anything. It's very likely that that is the issue because we've recently updated the jquery version.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass any non existing value(it is not necessary to pass "" ) to this method it will clear the select element since there is no matching option. Therefore use selected index to select option dynamically.

```
$("#list")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that *setting* the value for a `<select>` element causes a problem somewhere; possibly due to the `value` property being implemented/handled differently for `<select>` elements, for example:

```js
$('#dropdown').prop("value", function(){
  console.log(this.value, this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
  // 0 <option value="0">...</option>
}).val('').prop("value", function(){
  console.log(this.value, this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
  // undefined
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
  <option value="0">Option 0</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

To set the value to, for example, `1`:

```js
$('#dropdown').prop("selectedIndex", function () {
    return $('options[value="1"]', this).index();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
  <option value="0">Option 0</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Or:

```js
$('#dropdown option[value="1"]').prop("selected", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
  <option value="0">Option 0</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```